# How to authenticate a user using token from Google SignIn in backend server

Tags: ios, asp.net, authentication, owin, google-signin

I have ASP.NET MVC website where users con login using Google accounts. The google login is handled with OWIN Middleware in the server. So when the user decides to login with google in my website, they are taken to google page and OWIN generates **return url** like this:

https://myapp.com/signin-google?state=blabhlah&prompt=none

I have an iOS app which uses **Google Sign in** native library to login a user (displaying in-app safari like browser).

The `GIDSignIn` library returns to my app with an **access token** which i get from `user.authentication.idToken`

How can i authenticate this user in my ASP.NET web app? Is there a way to pipe in the access token so that my server can authenticate the user transparently, without adding extra code in the server?

I read i could send my accessToken via SSL to the server and Log in the user, is there a way OWIN can handle the access token?

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Comment: I ended up doing a custom endpoint which receives a goolge token and authenticates the user against google, so it is a custom solution, not OWIN.